# How to enable dictionary search in Google?

Tags: google-search

Ho do I enable Google dictionary search in Google web results?

If I do a google web search (e.g. for the word 'pertain') in my private gmail account, I don't get any Google Dictionary definitions. If I do the same search when logged in with my work gmail account (through google apps), I do get dictionary definitions. Why is that so?
I didn't find any settings to enable/disable this.

See screenshots below.

Google result with private Gmail account (does NOT show dictionary definitions):

[image: google result with private gmail account]

Google result with work Gmail account (does show dictionary definitions):
[image: google result with work gmail account]

Comment: If I recall, you can force a dictionary definition by using `define:{term}`, e.g., `define:pertain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with your language settings. Notice how the Google interface is in Flemish (*Afbeeldingen*, *Nieuws*, ...) using your private account, but in English (*Images*, *News*, ...) using the work account. I can reproduce this behaviour.

You can set your account language to English, if you'd like. Using your private account:

1. Go to http://www.google.com
2. In the bottom of the screen, click *Settings → Search settings*
3. Click the *Languages* tab, select *English* and *Save*.

Googling for English terms (like `pertain`) should now produce dictionary/definition results.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I already changed my language to English, but I only did that for my gmail *account*, and not the search settings.